`err-mimir-missing-metric-name` error when using remote-write endpoint in Mimir with the `__name__` label present
We seem to be getting err-mimir-missing-metric-name error when trying to insert custom metric records into Mimir via the remote_write endpoint. The problem is that we do have the metric name in the labels list, so it's not quite clear at what end the problem is.
Steps we're following:

download mimir proto file with its dependencies (we had to find all of them because it was not possible to compile just mimir.proto)

https://github.com/grafana/mimir/blob/main/pkg/mimirpb/mimir.proto
https://github.com/gogo/protobuf/blob/master/gogoproto/gogo.proto
https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto

compile all files with --js_out flag

To be able to do that we had to install protoc-gen-js via npm install -g protoc-gen-js. The compile command that was used is as follows:
protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:. mimir.proto gogo.proto descriptor.proto
The command generates CommonJS modules successfully.

import WriteRequest and other classes from the compiled mimir_pb.js file and construct the request object.

We try to send a custom metric called example_metric and are trying to attach uuid and status as labels.

serialize the object using serializeBinary method
compress the binary data using snappy
add compressed data to the POST request, add the following headers:

"Content-Encoding": "snappy"
"Content-Type": "application/x-protobuf"
"X-Prometheus-Remote-Write-Version": "0.1.0"

protobuf-javascript provides the .toObject() method, so before compressing it is possible to print out the constructed object that is going to be serialized as a WriteRequest, here it is:
{
timeseriesList: [
  {
    "labelsList": [
      {
        "name": "__name__",
        "value": "example_metric"
      },
      {
        "name": "status",
        "value": "up"
      },
      {
        "name": "uuid",
        "value": "c4a1d53b-454e-434d-8f93-11f0e9e0d10a"
      }
    ],
    "samplesList": [
      {
        "timestampMs": 1735044676736,
        "value": 1.1
      }
    ],
    "exemplarsList": [],
    "histogramsList": []
  }
]
source: 0
metadataList: [
  {
    "type": 0,
    "metricFamilyName": "example_metric",
    "help": "",
    "unit": ""
  }
]
skipLabelValidation: false
skipLabelCountValidation: false
}

Additional context:
libprotoc version is 3.21.12
OS Ubuntu 24
NodeJS version v18.20.5
Questions that we're interested in:

is there anything that we are not doing to successfully send a custom metric?
how can we find out at what end the problem is - ours or Mimir's?
is it possible to debug the message inside of Mimir to understand what gets validated there?


Are you sure that what you are trying is a good idea? I mean IIRC advice for remote-write was always "don't implement it yourself". Idea for it is that one compatible scraper might send metrics to another. And here it seems like you simply trying to get around pull nature of the approach.

And again, IIRC, general advice for situations like yours (if my guess was correct) is to expose metrics as normal, and then have something like Prometheus in agent mode or Grafana Agent to scrape them and remote-write to Mimir.

thanks @markalex you are probably right, we're reconsidering the approach
